# Using value from related table in LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I was expecting the following LINQ query to retrieve all contacts with the specified phone number but instead it returns all contacts that don't have a phone number at all.

```
var query = from contact in dc.Contacts
            where contact.Phones.All(phone => phone.PhoneNumber == "5558675309")
            select contact;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been using the Any extension method, not All.

The following code works just fine:

```
var query = from contact in dc.Contacts            
            where contact.Phones.Any(p => p.PhoneNumber == "5558675309")            
            select contact;
```